# What is SASL/GSSAPI?

Tags: linux, kerberos, sasl

Numerous times i have met the expression SASL/GSSAPI. I have searched Google many times, but i simply do no understand what it is and how it relate to Kerberos.

Anybody that have a simple explanation on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SASL and GSSAPI are frameworks that various authentication providers can be plugged into.  People wishing to use Kerberos authentication in an app that supports SASL or GSSAPI need only to provide the appropriate Kerberos plugin, rather than rewrite the app with Kerberos-specific code.

Comment: Indeed, as I said, "SASL . . . that various authentication providers can be plugged into".  They are two different frameworks that you can plug various authentication providers, such as Kerberos or NTLM, into.

Comment: SASL is more of a implementation specification usually for text based protocols (like SMTP, IMAP, etc). GSSAPI is an application interface definition for plugins that support various authentications mechanisms. SASL can use GSSAPI to extend it's auth mechanisms.

Comment: without giving a concrete '''example''' which actual provider plugs into which real-world  framework, most people don't know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 76):

[SASL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) stands for Simple Authentication and Security Layer; it's a framework that allows developers to implement different authentication mechanisms, and allows clients and servers to negotiate a mutually acceptable mechanism for each connection (rather than hard-coding or pre-configuring them).

[GSSAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface) stands for Generic Security Services Application Program Interface; it is usually made available as one of the mechanisms that SASL can use. It is itself another framework for developing and implementing various authentication mechanisms. These mechanisms include Kerberos, NTLM, and [SPNEGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO) (Simple and Protected GSSAPI Negotiation Mechanism): a GSSAPI pseudo-mechanism which allows GSSAPI-compatible clients to negotiate which GSSAPI mechanism they want to use.

Here's an example to help make this a little clearer (brutally simplified for clarity's sake):

1. Client connects to server and says, "I support SASL! How should I authenticate myself?"
2. Server receives the connection and responds, "I also support SASL, and can use these mechanisms, in descending order of preference: GSSAPI, CRAM-MD5, PLAIN."
3. Client responds, "Of the choices, I'd like to use GSSAPI."
4. Server responds "GSSAPI? Capital. I support Kerberos and NTLM."
5. Client responds "Let's use Kerberos. Here's my encrypted ticket etc. etc."

Comment: A great example for a quote from Albert Einstein: "If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough." :)

Comment: From what I read in [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer). On step 2, the server should include NTLM, not after the client has chosen GSSAPI?