# Add GSSAPI to OpenLdap in supportedSASLMechanisms

Tags: openldap, sasl, gssapi, ldapmodule

I'm looking **how to add the GSSAPI support into my OpenLDAP** ?

**Current setup**

```
MIT Kerberos V + OpenLDAP
Kerberos bind to openldap
Able to issue kerberos tickets to my users (with kinit exampluser)
Able to ldapsearch -x uid=exampluser
```

**Openldap side**

```
server% ldapsearch -x -H ldapi:/// -b "" -LLL -s base -Z supportedSASLMechanisms

    ldap_start_tls: Protocol error (2)
    additional info: unsupported extended operation
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: EXTERNAL
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
supportedSASLMechanisms: LOGIN
supportedSASLMechanisms: PLAIN
```

**Client Side**

```
client% ldapsearch uid=exampleuser

SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Authentication method not supported (7)
    additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Couldn't find mech GSSAPI
```

**Client ldap.conf**

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE        dc=example,dc=com
URI         ldap://ldap.example.com
SASL_MECH   GSSAPI
```

Obviously, the error is clear enough to explain that my ldap request didn't find the mechanism to auth.

I've been through many tutorial, explanations, but still can't find anywhere how to "**add**" that mechanism.

Thanks [What is SASL/GSSAPI?](https://serverfault.com/questions/139896/what-is-sasl-gssapi) for all the awesome explanations.

**Updated for user 473183469**

I've generated a keytab just for the ldap, that I've copied in **/etc/ldap/ldap.keytab**, and edited the **/etc/default/slapd** according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SingleSignOn asking to uncomment and give the path to **export KRB5_KTNAME=/etc/ldap/ldap.keytab**

That ldap keytab was generated like that

```
kadmin: addprinc -randkey ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin: ktadd -k ~/ldap.keytab ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

I also have a /etc/krb5.keytab that was created at the beginning of the installation

```
kadmin.local:  listprincs
admin@EXAMPLE.COM
K/M@EXAMPLE.COM
krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/changepw@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/history@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
user1@example.com (also in the ldap, can issue a ticket and everything)
user2@example.com (same for him)
ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

The ktutil result

```
# ktutil
ktutil:  read_kt /etc/ldap.keytab
ktutil:  list
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    2            ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2    2            ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   3    2            ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4    2            ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
ktutil:  read_kt /etc/krb5.keytab
ktutil:  list
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    2            ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2    2            ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   3    2            ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4    2            ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5    2           kadmin/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   6    2           kadmin/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   7    2           kadmin/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   8    2           kadmin/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I was missing `SASL_MECH GSSAPI` and `SASL_REAM` in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`

```
[Tue Feb 28 13:48 root:ldap] [~] # cat /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=example,dc=com
URI ldap://ldap.example.com    
SASL_MECH GSSAPI
SASL_REALM EXAMPLE.COM
```

Now I can just ldapsearch uid=user directly with a kerberos ticket and get the

```
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: user@EXAMPLE.COM
SASL SSF: 112
SASL data security layer installed.
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: uid=user
# requesting: ALL
#
```

Of course, if I don't have a kerberos ticket (which makes sense)

```
client% ldapsearch uid=gleger
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
    additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found)
```

Comment: While I'm glad you got your system working, I doubt that the answer you've provided is correct. As `ldap.conf` applies strictly to clients it should not alter the `supportedSASLMechanisms` provided by a server.  From `LDAP.CONF(5)`: `The ldap.conf configuration file is used to set system-wide defaults to be applied when running ldap clients.`

Comment: True. I  will give a look tomorrow to that slapd.conf file actually, might be actually the "good" answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change your sasl configuration for slapd, usually `/etc/sasl2/slapd.conf`, to include gssapi.

For example:

```
mech_list: external gssapi plain
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
```

You'll need to restart slapd afterwards.

Comment: I use cn=config for my ldap, not the slapd.conf file. Whoever, I've got a /etc/ldap/sasl2 folder that is empty ?

Comment: Despite the name is the same, there is a different `slapd.conf`just for SASL. It is another thing in respect to your `cn=config` slapd.d. Please give a try to what super-competent user 84104 told.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you simply missing the `/etc/krb5.keytab` file having as SPN `ldap/fdqn`?

I don't think you need to set any of the GSSAPI-related SASL switch on OpenLDAP as the defaults are fine and forcing e.g. the realm is more trouble than other.

Comment: I've edited the question. Should I then use the krb5.keytab on the ldap ? and not generate a special one just for him ?

Comment: no, it looks fine. Actually I use a system-wide krb5.keytab file good for ssh as well as for OpenLDAP, but as you did looks fine.

Comment: Even on the user side, when I try to ldapsearch, I received a krbtg/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM

Comment: Did you install OpenLDAP from packages? Have you installed the proper sasl-modules: `libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit`, for Debian?

Comment: libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit is already the newest version. :(

Comment: Just for fun, what about switching the `mit` libraries with the `heimdal` ones?

Comment: I can, but I'm using the MIT kerberos, will it affect it in any way ?